# How do I display database statistics in Darktable?

Tags: photo-management

Is there a way of showing stats abut the whole Darktable system?
I would be interested in things like...

- number of images

  - by camera
  - by file type
- current queue stats

  - how many (if any) images still need to be indexed
- how much space is taken up by

  - thumbnails
  - image fingerprints
  - metadata
  - ...
- live stats:

  - CPU usage
  - GPU usage (seems to me more important for this application anyway)

Comment: could somebody please create a Darktable tag? thats the only one that I would have chosen if it existed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [script](http://www.christianroessler.net/tech/2014/darktable-library-statistics-script.html) for that particular task.
Based upon bash with a bit of sqlite3.

Requirements to query against the darktable-library:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Greetings,
Christian